# Is it ok to disable admob ads in my app (for premium user) like this?

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin, admob, ads

I have integrated admob ads in my app. And I have a system in my app to let users disable ads. They have to spend 1000 gems per day, Gems is an In App currency which can be earn by using the app or can be purchased, I am using Stripe to make perchases. So when the user spends 1000 gems, I set the boolean field, adsEnabled to false. And when user opens a page with ads in it, it first checks the value of the boolean field, if true then it shows ads if not then no ads are shown. Will this make admob ban me or rather, is this a legit way to do this?

Comment: No, AdMob won't ban you if you do not show ads to your users. This is a common use-case to allow users to remove ads via a Purchase. However I am not sure if Google Play would allow using Stripe as a payment method here.

Comment: I am not a fan of admob because I get banned just about every time for invalid clicks for a single banner ad in its own container away from the core app.. however, from what I have gathered in my experience is you need to have to flavors. One for ads one for not. Also as far as I know you can no longer use stripe for payments per their new policy. That’s why I am having to rethink my games

Comment: @Darshan new policy states any third party payment is not allowed. But OP would have to use flavors or a separate build to show the non ad portion. I get hit with a violation on one of my apps for the same thing OP is trying to do. Google Console and Admob needs to get on same page with this stuff

Comment: No, you do not need to have flavors to give users an Ad-Free experience. You can create your logic with GooglePlay's purchase APIs & provide an ad free experience to the users on a successful purchase or subscription. Creating flavors is indeed a choice but not a requirement here. As for the payments, OP needs to use Google Play's Billing here & lose a 15% cut on them.